# adding node.js directory to cygwin path breaks the ls command

Tags: cygwin, node.js

adding node.js directory to cygwin path breaks the ls command:

```
Starting /bin/bash.exe

myidt@DESKTOP-IV5C6TI /cygdrive/d/tmp/node_ls_ko
$ touch toto

user@DESKTOP /cygdrive/d/tmp/node_ls_ko
$ ls
toto

user@DESKTOP /cygdrive/d/tmp/node_ls_ko
$ PATH=/cygdrive/d/brl/app/node-v14.17.6-win-x64:%PATH%

user@DESKTOP /cygdrive/d/tmp/node_ls_ko
$ ls
bash: ls : commande introuvable
```

Of course the node dir contains nothing looking like "ls":

as shown by the following in a new cygwin terminal:

```
$ ls /cygdrive/d/brl/app/node-v14.17.6-win-x64
asciidoctor-pdf          asciidoctor-web-pdf.ps1  install_tools.bat  node.exe               npm
asciidoctor-pdf.cmd      CHANGELOG.md             jhipster           node_etw_provider.man  npm.cmd
asciidoctor-pdf.ps1      inliner                  jhipster.cmd       node_modules           npx
asciidoctor-web-pdf      inliner.cmd              jhipster.ps1       nodevars.bat           npx.cmd
asciidoctor-web-pdf.cmd  inliner.ps1              LICENSE            nodevars_my.bat        README.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the assignment, you need `$PATH` instead of `%PATH%`. The former syntax is used by *nix systems, and the latter by Windows CMD. Cygwin emulates POSIX environments, so the former syntax is required.

The current statement assigns the literal string '%PATH%' to the path variable, making it unable to find the `/usr/bin/ls` command.

Comment: my bad, thanks !